# SAML2 metadata endpoint in Spring Security 5.4.0-RC1 not enabled by default

Tags: spring-security

I wanted to try the new SAML2 Metadata endpoint in Spring Security 5.4.0-RC1 (with Spring Boot 2.3.2) but accessing `/saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registrationId}` returns 404.

I had to add the filter myself, like this:

```
@Bean
public Saml2MetadataFilter saml2MetadataFilter(RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository repository) {
    return new Saml2MetadataFilter(new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(repository), new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
}
```

Then the metadata endpoint works as expected.

Is this by design or is there a missing configuration on my part or in Spring Security?

I searched for `Saml2MetadataFilter` in the spring security repository on GitHub but only found it in a test.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: The Spring Security SAML2 documentation is now updated with instructions on how to enable the metadata endpoint.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.0/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login-metadata

This instruction make sure `Saml2MetadataFilter` is added before the `Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter` so it's always publicly accessible.